# Where is located the ServiceDefinition.csdef file?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm following this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433110.aspx to configure a Web Role for Multiple Web Sites, in that tutorial they say that I should open the **ServiceDefinition.csdef** file, but I do not know where that file is located, what is the route to find that file?

Comment: How are you creating your cloud service files in the first place? PowerShell? Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio to create this file (and other necessary files into the project) prior to configure a web role:

1) Install the sdk for your chosen language.

http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/downloads/

2) In Visual Studo, create a new cloud project

3) Add the roles you want to use, ie. for a website, add a web role.

If you don't want to use visual studio, you can create a standard cloud service project using the powershell cmdlet. This is the layer that goes above your web project.

New-AzureServiceProject

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495188.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers his question about where that specific file is located...

Comment: The file doesn't create by itself magically that's why he need either use VS or Powershell cmdlet. He jumped a step following the tutorial.

Comment: Or it could have been created by hand though... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio then it is found in the Cloud Project (ccproj) Root directory after project creation.